Are there specific `LaTeX3` commands for coding classes?
I'd like to write my first LaTeX class.
Are there any LaTeX3 commands specifically for coding classes? I'm not talking about general LaTeX3 coding, just class-specific stuff.

In general you should follow the guidelines in clsguide that is distributed with LaTeX.  Many of the commands provided in newer releases such as \ProcessKeyOptions are written internally using L3 programming layer commands, but they have been given traditional 2e syntax.
If the body of your code is in L3 syntax you may prefer to use \ProvidesExplClass rather than \ProvidesClass at the start of the file as this will take care of switching to L3 syntax and save explicit use of \ExplSyntaxOn.
